# Why is DCOS required if we can deploy Mesos Cluster directly

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I have an query, If we can use Mesos Cluster by directly installing master and slave nodes. Then why do we need DCOS , is it  that DCOS provides additional support along with mesos cluster. Please elaborate on this part.

Comment: It's a bit like asking: why do we need Ubuntu or CentOS if we can have the Linux kernel directly.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your needs :-):
Here what in my opinion the Community Edition (the Enterprise Edition includes more proprietary features such as security) of DCOS adds to self setup of Mesos:

- Easy setup, including [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon) and [MesosDNS](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns).
- [Command Line Interface](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-cli) with one Click install from the [Universe](https://github.com/mesosphere/universe). I personally especially like the simple installs of these services as it is really simple to install for example HDFS or cassandra in your cluster. **Note**: As with the above you can probably with some effort configure such setup yourself as both projects are on Github.
- Very nice UI

So overall I would summarize DCOS provides a very easy and tested best-practice setup of Mesos and its ecosystem.

Hope this helps!